# Rails: jQuery Ajax issue with partial refresh of comment section

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I currently have a comment section that posts only after the whole page refreshes. Although after the post the page refreshes by itself it feels inefficient for the whole page to refresh. I was wondering if anyone can help me with a js file that would refresh just that partial, I am still shakey with my js. Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!

This is my current js for the **create.js**:

`$("#comments").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @micropost.comments)) %>");`

**comment controller**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController 
  def create
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
    @comment = @micropost.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    @comment.save 
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

**Comment Section**

```
<div id='CommentContainer-<%= micropost.id%>' class='CommentContainer Condensed2'>
<div class='Comment'>
<%= render :partial => "comments/form", :locals => { :micropost => micropost } %>
</div>
<div id='comments'>
<%=render micropost.comments %>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something like this in your controller. This will trigger both the js and html templates as needed.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController 
  respond_to :html
  respond_to :js, only: [ :create ]

  def create
    # ...
    respond_with @comment if @comment.save
  end

  def index
    @comments = Microcomment.find(params[:id]).comments
    respond_with @comments
  end
end
```

This will then require views/comments/create.js to respond with something like:

```
// create.js.erb
$("#comments").get("/api/micropost/<%= @micropost.id %>/comments");
```

And the view for the comments will be `index.html.erb`

```
# index.html.erb
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <!-- Display your comment here -->
<% end %>
```

Now all you have to do is set up a `match` for `/api/micropost/:id/comments` in your routes, and this can then serve the list  of comments in the desired html format.

Note that this is not completely restful, but I like to keep the `/api` there to distinguish calls coming from xhr on a url level.

Comment: This method seems to be doing what it always does rather now it refreshes the whole page and goes to `http://localhost:3000/microposts/21/comments` and doesnt go back to the original page